# LDAP migrate from BDB to MDB version 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: openldap

I have ran into two problems with a ldap migration.
As i understand it BDB is not supported on openldap 2.6 so i should move to mdb on my working 2.4 openldap and then migrate to 2.6 (on a new server) after.

These are the steps i have taken to move from a BDB to MDB

```
systemctl stop slapd
slapcat -n 0 -l backup.ldif | slapadd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
```

Edit the slapd.conf file changing the line

```
database bdb
```

to

```
database mdb
```

finally

```
slapadd -l backup.ldif -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
```

This last step is where i get issues. The error message is

```
65f1cb5d /etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 16: <suffix> invalid DN 21 (Invalid syntax)
slapadd: bad configuration file!
```

My suffix hasnt change from the working bdb and as far as i am aware should be correct
the line in my conf file is

```
suffix "dc=*my_company*,dc=net"
```

Im at a loss to why im getting this problem and for all my searching cant find the solution to this, i really dont understand where ive gone wrong.